# What is Aarya Upavaada?

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, reference-request, academic-buddhism

Based on a real situation, I have come across some people who claim to be Sotapanna and Sakadaagaami.. When i have gotten angry or upset about something they said or did, i was told i am committing Aarya Upavaada. This is nothing to do with Dhamma but personal issues such as relationships and finances. I am told if i get angry or upset with them, i am still committing Aarya Upavaada as the people involved are Aarya.

With Sutta references, could someone tell me if this is indeed Aarya Upavaada and what actually constitutes Aarya Upavaada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear Gaveshika… if those people that you have come across are the type that tells any Tom, Dick or Harry that they meet that they are Sotapanna and Sakadaagaami, then you have nothing to fear. Only to such a person who has similar characteristics (gathi) as him/her, would a Sotapanna reveal that he/she is one such. By that what I mean is that, if an ordinary run-of-the-mill person asks you whether you a Sotapanna, you will evade that question, as this knowledge is something that you keep very close to your heart. So no fear, you have not committed an Aarya Upavaada.

But in case you had (even inadvertently) done a Aarya Upavaada to someone who walks this Noble Path that day, you could think about that person and ask for forgiveness. This is a very effective way to calm the mind and reduce tensions. If done sincerely, you should be able to see the effects in real life. You may notice that the tensions with that person is automatically reduced.
..........

A person who treads this Path in all sincerity knows at every stage where s/he is at.  One realizes that one is a Sotapanna, but it happens with time. When one observes oneself, it becomes clear to oneself that one has removed the characteristics (gathi) that prevents one from becoming such, and that you have attained that precious thing/stage sought by a Bhauddhaya (or a practicing Buddhist). Also, when you observe such characteristics (gathi) in a another (be it a much sought-after monk) you begin to question as to how that person could even be a Sotapanna. But you guard yourself and do not entertain such thoughts, as only a Buddha can say for sure whether a given person other than you, has attained magga phala or not. In this Path you will ONLY concern about yourself and NOT any other.

At this stage you do not need any guidance from another. You have seen the way to Nibbana (or a glimpse of Nibbana). You know what’s to be done, and silently you go about it, and your neighbours and others that you come across in your daily life will never know that you are one such (a Sotapanna). Once that knowledge that you have arrived at this stage of Sotapanna sinks in, your attitude, behavior, and outlook on life has changed forever.

Observing another person’s characteristics (gathi), you then get a feeling that there is a greater likelihood that the other person is at the Sotapanna stage or higher. ONLY with such a person would you share this kind of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. Both persons I refer to, tell people they are "Aarya" and "Maarga Pala Laabhi", even if such people are not ones with similar gathi. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: May be I will try to expand on what I said above, for you to better understand the 'Gathi' of a Sotapanna.  - with metta.

Answer (score 1):

0.0. Talking, speech, blaming, teaching with any 5 hindrances could be [5 Cetokhila](http://www.suttas.com/mn-16-cetokhila-sutta-the-wilderness-in-the-heart.html). Actually, all of them are the barrier of enlightenment, not only blaming by anger.

0.1. We shouldn't angry anyone, even though that one is not ariya. And we can't know the truth exactly  if we have no 8 vijja skills (8 genuine awarenesses), so it is very easy to distort the truth, wrong speech. Be quiet is easier than undo spoken speech.

0.2. Upavada is blaming by angry. See Sutta. Aṅ. (2): catukkanipāto
Bhayavaggo tatiyo
[121]   [Attānuvādasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=21&A=3338&eng=metta)  .

1. The blaming can done by a wholesome mind, such as the blaming  when Buddha created each vinaya rule, or by an unwholesome mind, such as ariya-upavada.
2. That unwholesome mind of upavada can take 2 object types:  wrong condition object of under sotapanna's, and  right condition object, sotapanna's and sakadagami's mind.

2.1. Example of wrong condition object: Under sotapanna blame an arahanta-bhikkhu  "you are immoral (because you make love with a lady)". This case is fail, because arahanta doesn't has caving left to making love, except raped or sleeping.

2.2. Example of right condition object: the sotapanna blame an arahanta-bhikkhu  "you are immoral (because you let your tear wet the Buddha's foots)". This case can be right because tearing Buddha's foots is not a good action, however if that sotapanna blame by unwholesome mind, angry, it is upavada.

Answer (score 0):

Upavada is rooted in anger or Patigha which is a unwholesome or akusala mental formation or chayithasika with  unwholesome results or vipaka whether you commit the act verbally, physically or mentally to an Aarya or non-Aarya person. Of course done to an Aarya is more grievous especially done to an Arhath or The Buddha.
Only the Buddha has proclaimed himself(Sinhanada sutta)to be Fully Enlightened without being asked.Often it is the Buddha who  announces that such and such desciple is now achieved Arahant status. IMHO any one who brags that he/she is Sotapanna is a  charlatan!

Answer (score 0):

People are egotistical, have delusions of grandeur, and use religion (Buddhism, Christianity, Islam, it doesn't matter which one) to reinforce their delusions of grandeur. If someone is showing obvious signs of being offended easily by having their claims questioned, if they show egotism, claiming that you disagreeing with them is tantamount to disagreeing with the Buddha himself, then they are clearly not a stream-entrant. It isn't your job to convince them that they are not. Likely, no one could. Don't worry yourself over narcissists on the Internet. My advice.